# Spring RESTfull Web Service + AngularJS HTTP 404 error

Tags: java, spring, angularjs

I'm trying to consume webservice on my local machine and use `AngularJS` $http. Via browser everything works fine and I receive correct `JSON` response. 
But with `AngularJS` $http I receive 404 error, however, handler is found and response is being generated.

FrontEnd:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8080/apartments.json').
            success(function(data){
                $scope.apartments = data;
            }).
            error(function(data, status){
                alert("Error "+ status);
            });
```

BackEnd:

```
@Controller
public class ApartmentsController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/apartments", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<ApartmentEntity> getAll(){
        ApartmentEntity apartmentEntity = new ApartmentEntity();
        apartmentEntity.setName("test");
        apartmentEntity.setPrice(1000);
        return Arrays.asList(apartmentEntity);
    }
}
```

Servlet is mapped correctly.

Could you please suggest what is wrong?

Comment: Where are you serving the angular html file from?

Comment: It's separate web-server on the same machine.

Comment: The vital question here is if your RESTful endpoint is being served under the same origin as your client application. If that is the case, then we can delve into why the endpoint is not being hit. Otherwise, we may need to talk about CORS or proxying strategies.

Comment: In fact, Websevice is being hit from browser and from client side as well. I suspected the issue with cross domain request, but i don't receive any message regarding it. Only 404 error.

Comment: @shevchik I think you are not getting my question. Can you tell me the  protocol, hostname and port for your RESTful server, and the same for the one serving your application? For instance, RESTful server is: `http://localhost:8080` and Web application is being reached from `http://localhost:4040`. Then you have a CORS conflict.

Comment: Edwin, yes, backend and frontend are deployed on different servers. I thought that it might be an issue. But why do I get 404 error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Angular is by default trying to use [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) as this is an ajax request attempt from one page loaded from one server to a REST service running in another server.

The way it tries to use CORS is by issuing the GET with a default header that triggers the browser to do a 'pre-flight' `OPTIONS`request.

This pre-flight automatic `OPTIONS` request is for the browser to get the list of supported methods by the server, and this is the first step of CORS.

So the 404 comes from this `OPTIONS` request.

See this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1454) in Angular, it seems that this was fixed in more recent versions as it was causing a lot of questions from users. See also the [original issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1585) that triggered the fix.

In you case for local development you can always deploy both applications in the same server and the problem is solved.

If in production it's necessary to run frontend/backend on separate servers, then either proxy those servers by a common frontend server like nginx/Apache or or turn on CORS, see [enable-cors.org](http://enable-cors.org/server.html).

Comment: Thanks for explanation where does 404 error come from

Comment: @shevchik An alternative approach to enabling CORS (which may not be always possible [not speaking technically]) is to proxy your requests. That is, all RESTful endpoint requests, can be forwarded by you own web application server to the appropriate RESTful endpoint server. Since the server-side is not subject to CORS.